# Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS, tried everything still fails

Tags: javascript, api, axios, cors, azure-functions

I'm using AXIOS to make a get request to my azure function that is running locally. I get this issue. Seems to be a common issue, and I've tried the solutions, it was working, but now it stopped working. What I changed is I added entity framework and some code, don't know how to resolve this.
*Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7071/api/Function1' from origin 'https://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.*
tried these solutions, the localsettingsjson solution was working and now it stopped i dont know why:

```
  "Host": {
    "CORS": "*" 
  }
```

I added this to my localsettingsjson
I tried starting the function with this command

EDIT:
I wonder if my local settings json is being read at all because I deleted everything in it, and function still starts.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using XMLHttpRequest instead of axios in javascript.

I'm testing axios to see if it works by adding this because that's the only difference I think:

```
  const config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
  }
```

EDIT: OK adding, content-type headers didn't fix it. I don't know why Axios just doesn't work. If you're facing this issue use XMLHttpRequest instead.